# Four datetimes objects touching/overlaping each other

Tags: c#, datetime, overlap

I'm trying to find out whether 2 `DateTime` objects touch/overlap each other with other 2 `DateTime` objects.

There are a lot of cases which I'm trying to check for. But I was wondering if there is any efficient way of doing this differently? A `LINQ` extension perhaps?

```
public IQueryable<Appointment> GetAllAppointments(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
        {
            return _dbContext.Appointment.Where(x => x.Appointment.StartTime <= startTime && x.Appointment.EndTime >= endTime && x.Appointment.StartTime <= endTime && x.Appointment.EndTime <= startTime
                                    || x.Appointment.StartTime >= startTime && x.Appointment.EndTime <= endTime && x.Appointment.StartTime <= endTime && x.Appointment.EndTime <= startTime
                                    || x.Appointment.StartTime == startTime && x.Appointment.EndTime == endTime && x.Appointment.StartTime <= endTime && x.Appointment.EndTime <= startTime
                                    || x.Appointment.StartTime >= startTime && x.Appointment.EndTime >= endTime
                                    || x.Appointment.StartTime <= startTime && x.Appointment.EndTime >= endTime);
        }
```

The appointments shouldn't be 'touching' each other. When an appointment is ended, the next start appointment shouldn't start at the date and time where the previous date and time ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET) to detect overlapping/touching time periods:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void TimeRangeSample()
{
  // --- time range 1 ---
  TimeRange timeRange1 = new TimeRange(
    new DateTime( 2011, 2, 22, 14, 0, 0 ),
    new DateTime( 2011, 2, 22, 18, 0, 0 ) );
  Console.WriteLine( "TimeRange1: " + timeRange1 );
  // > TimeRange1: 22.02.2011 14:00:00 - 18:00:00 | 04:00:00

  // --- time range 2 ---
  TimeRange timeRange2 = new TimeRange(
    new DateTime( 2011, 2, 22, 15, 0, 0 ),
    new TimeSpan( 2, 0, 0 ) );
  Console.WriteLine( "TimeRange2: " + timeRange2 );
  // > TimeRange2: 22.02.2011 15:00:00 - 17:00:00 | 02:00:00

  // --- time range 3 ---
  TimeRange timeRange3 = new TimeRange(
    new DateTime( 2011, 2, 22, 16, 0, 0 ),
    new DateTime( 2011, 2, 22, 21, 0, 0 ) );
  Console.WriteLine( "TimeRange3: " + timeRange3 );
  // > TimeRange3: 22.02.2011 16:00:00 - 21:00:00 | 05:00:00

  // --- relation ---
  Console.WriteLine( "TimeRange1.GetRelation( TimeRange2 ): " +
                     timeRange1.GetRelation( timeRange2 ) );
  // > TimeRange1.GetRelation( TimeRange2 ): Enclosing
  Console.WriteLine( "TimeRange1.GetRelation( TimeRange3 ): " +
                     timeRange1.GetRelation( timeRange3 ) );
  // > TimeRange1.GetRelation( TimeRange3 ): EndInside
  Console.WriteLine( "TimeRange3.GetRelation( TimeRange2 ): " +
                     timeRange3.GetRelation( timeRange2 ) );
  // > TimeRange3.GetRelation( TimeRange2 ): StartInside

  // --- intersection ---
  Console.WriteLine( "TimeRange1.GetIntersection( TimeRange2 ): " +
                     timeRange1.GetIntersection( timeRange2 ) );
  // > TimeRange1.GetIntersection( TimeRange2 ):
  //             22.02.2011 15:00:00 - 17:00:00 | 02:00:00
  Console.WriteLine( "TimeRange1.GetIntersection( TimeRange3 ): " +
                     timeRange1.GetIntersection( timeRange3 ) );
  // > TimeRange1.GetIntersection( TimeRange3 ):
  //             22.02.2011 16:00:00 - 18:00:00 | 02:00:00
  Console.WriteLine( "TimeRange3.GetIntersection( TimeRange2 ): " +
                     timeRange3.GetIntersection( timeRange2 ) );
  // > TimeRange3.GetIntersection( TimeRange2 ):
  //             22.02.2011 16:00:00 - 17:00:00 | 01:00:00
} // TimeRangeSample
```

Comment: Does this work with LINQ 2 Entities? Or should i get a list first then loop through it?

Comment: You should loop through your entities and fill a `TimePeriodCollection`. The `TimePeriodCollection` provides also support to detect overlapping/touching time periods.

Comment: How does the TimePeriodCollection 'knows' which 2 dates belong to each other and to which to compare?

Comment: it seems that the `TimePeriodCollection` checks for all dates that intersect with each other. But I need it to check it against 1 period range. I don't see how to accomplish that.